# Apache URL Rewrite: Dealing with Two Similar Rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

**Question:**

How do I write rules when they are similar?

**My Rules:**

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/[-0-9a-zA-Z]+/?$ index.php?action=blog&postID=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/[-0-9a-zA-Z]+/?$ index.php?action=blog&category=$1 [NC]
```

**What I am trying to accomplish is:**

`domain.com/blog/1/title-of-post` and `domain.com/blog1/name-of-category`

Is this possible? What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the URIs are slightly different you should be able to use this in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+) index.php?action=blog&postID=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog([0-9]+)/ index.php?action=blog&category=$1 [L]
```

We do not need the `[NC]` flag because we're only matching a number. The `[L]` flag tells Apache to stop processing if there is a match. Since you're not doing anything with the titles there is no need to search all the way to the end of the line. Once we find the *postID* or *category* we should have all of our info.

To match both at the same time you might try this in a single rule.

```
RewriteRule ^blog([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) index.php?action=blog&category=$1&postID=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+) index.php?action=blog&postID=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog([0-9]+)/ index.php?action=blog&category=$1 [L]
```

If you're setting up the `Virtual Hosts` then you'll have to add the preceding slashes:

```
RewriteRule ^/blog/([0-9]+) /index.php?action=blog&postID=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/blog([0-9]+)/ /index.php?action=blog&category=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot my parenthesis initially... it's been a long 34 hour day.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. That will work for my needs. Btw, enjoyed your bio. Check mine out too.